# Sharing current loaded URL of webview

Tags: android, webview

How can I get and share the current URL that has been loaded in webview? I already have share but it shares the main URL.

Here is my code for sharing:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    ShareActionProvider mShare = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, webView.getUrl());
    mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, webView.getUrl());
    mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Comment: Dose you mean once webview is launched, user navigates to another page by clicking on hyperlink. Now you want to track this or share this new url?

Comment: @AnuragSingh exactly

Answer (score 0):

Set a `WebViewClient` with  the following code:

```
    private Sting mTrackUrlChange; //url for sharing
    private WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // Loading started for URL
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // Redirecting to URL
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Loading finished for URL
    mTrackUrlChange = url;
    }
    };
```

Now set it in code as: `webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);`

Declare a class member and assign this member the value of `url` from `onPageFinished`

Comment: @kielou What happened?

Comment: still sharing the original URL

Comment: Hmm.. can you explain this part? "Declare a class member and assign this member the value of `url` from `onPageFinished`"
Do I have something to change or add in my sharing code?

Comment: Yes that is the key part.  Declare a class member means just define a global variable. Use this global variable to keep track of url from onPageFinished. Look for variable private Sting mTrackUrlChange. Use mTrackUrlChange for sharing the url. Also, note that url can be tracked only if url changes in web address bar. yes you need to change the code as as I have post in answer section.

Comment: @kielou Did you make it work?  You should also share the url in onPageFinished and not in onCreateOptionsMenu. The value of url will be null mostly.